# An unhandled exception in Mapper or Reducer Task would make the task failed?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am wondering if an unhandled exception in a mapper task (or a reducer task) would make the task failed or only the particular input pair of the time would be ignored? I guess it is the former but not so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the exception is not recurring (i.e. a retry will succeed), then it will fail the task but the task will be retried (or a speculative execution running in parallel may proceed).  If the exception will always occur (e.g. there is bad input data) then retries will continue to fail and eventually the whole job will fail.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the error.  Either way, I always make it a point to wrap the map and reduce logic with try-catch blocks.  On an error, I increment a counter whose name is derived from the exception class name.  This not only protects the rest of hadoop from logic errors, but gives you an idea of how much went wrong just by looking at the logs.